# How To Design a MFC Application That Will Work On All Resolutions

Tags: windows, visual-c++, mfc, screen-resolution, dialogbasedapp

I'm currently working on the MFC application in Visual Studio 2017 which is having the dialogs designed for resolution 1920 x 1080, but now I want to modify it and make it scalable for all resolution.

What changes should I make to the application so that the application fits to all the screen size irrespective of resolution.

Comment: *"the application automatically fits"* - There's nothing *"automatic"* to be done here. It's manual work all the way through (design, implementation, testing). If you ever wondered why it took Visual Studio literally decades to implement a resizable Options dialog, you're on your way to find out how difficult that is. As an aside: Changing the DPI setting isn't going to change anything other than making the display more or less blurry.

Comment: I do understand that nothing can be done "automatically" but please do let us know what are all the options available to do it manually through code.